# Baker and Copson "The Mathematical Theory of Huygens Principle" 1987 page 17

Tags: waves

In Baker and Copson "The Mathematical Theory of Huygens Principle" page 17, how is this equation derived (after the first paragraph): 
$ R_0 r sin(\theta) d\theta = R dR $  I don't even know where $d\theta$ or $dR $ came from, although the figure on p 16 helps a little.  Baker reproduced these results from "Wave-motions with Discontinuities at Wave-fronts" A. E. H. Love, proc. london math. soc. (1904) s2-1:291-344.  But this paper does not clear things up for me either. Thanks if you can help.

page 16 and top of page 17:
[image: page 16]

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more context to this, so that those of us who do not have the book can potentially be of use.

Comment: I will do that when I figure out how to scan a few pages into my question (I'm new to stackexchange).  Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: @user45664 please don't scan pages into your question. Just retype the relevant parts. You don't have to add much; a few sentences is usually enough, if you choose the right ones. If it would help to add the figure, that you can scan, just don't include any substantial amount of text as an image.

Comment: Hi user45664: I believe that the [tag:mathematical-physics] tag does not apply to this question, cf. its [tag wiki](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics).

Comment: Baker and Copson in the preface say its a book on mathematical physics. I think its classical mathematical physics as in the Courant and Hilbert. Also note the book title.

Comment: Now I have uploaded a small scan of the relevant material from Baker and Copson. Hope it is enough.

Comment: The equation in question is at the very bottom of the scan.

Comment: @user45664 The locution _mathematical physics_ doesn’t mean now what it used to mean at the time of Courant&Hilbert (remember the first edition predates _e.g._ von Neumann’s work). It has spilled over to other books written after the tide had changed, but now this usage is almost archaic. (To everyone but the authors of Russian university physics curricula, but I’m digressing.) After von Neumann, the meaning of _mathematical physics_ shifted to what you can see in Reed&Simon, but even that sense is now out of date. Not to say this makes the material of C&H or R&S any less important, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you understand that the first part of the last equation $R^2 = R_0^2 + r^2 - 2R_0r\cos\theta$ follows from the the [Law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

To get the next equation, simply differentiate both sides while keeping $R_0$ and $r$ constant to give you

$$ 2RdR = 0 + 0 - 2R_0r(-\sin\theta)d\theta$$

which simplifies to

$$ RdR = R_0r\sin\theta d\theta$$

EDIT: If this way of differentiating is confusing, differentiate $R$ with respect to $\theta$, and then multiply the expression by $d\theta$, i.e.

$$ 2R\frac{dR}{d\theta} = - 2R_0r(-\sin\theta)$$

Mathematicians would probably cringe at this use of "infinitesimals", but is something is that does often in physics.

Comment: That is just super--thank you very much!!! Obviously that gets the results, and obviously Love, and also Baker and Copson did that. But I am still confused: you have differentiated the left side with respect to R, and the right side with respect to theta?? Is there the same operation that is applied to each side that yields this result? And when is it allowed to do this?  THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: It helps to think of R as R($\theta$)

Comment: @peanut_butter Though not commonly used or known among mathematicians, there’s a completely rigorous sense in which your use of infinitesimals is valid. There is an [explanation](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&lpg=PA165&pg=PA20) in Arnold’s _Ordinary Differential Equations_, Ch. 1 §6.